# Google Drive Picker ViewId.SPREADSHEET showing spreadsheets and forms

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

Is there a way to limit the Google Drive picker to spreadsheets only. I am adding the spreadsheet view id (per the below script from Google's documentation), however it is showing both Sheets and Forms.

```
function createPicker(token) {
  if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
        // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
        .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
        // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
        .hideTitleBar()
        .setOAuthToken(token)
        .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
        // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
        .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
            DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
        .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **create a view** (note `view.setMimeTypes`):

```
// Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
// views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS);
view.setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet');
view.setIncludeFolders(true);
```

then **add the view** to the picker:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().addView(view)
```

Comment: Thanks Kos, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by [setting the MIME](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference) type. The MIME types can be found [here.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types)

```
PickerBuilder.setSelectableMimeTypes(string)
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. This did restrict the selectable file types, but I prefer to not have the forms showing at all. The answer from Kos allows this. Thank you for your response though.